# How to re-create a time machine sparsebundle filde from a folder?

Tags: mac

I've a TimeMachine backup on a synology NAS, it created a .sparsebundle file.
My Mac TimeMachine doesn't reconnect to this TimeMachine backup.
So I copied the .sparsebundle on my mac and it can't mount (I've tried all the fixex on the internel hdutil attch - can't be mounted).
However, the Nas Fiestation utility is able to browse the .sparsebundle file as if it was a folder. So I asked Filestation to copy all its content to a aniother folder, that wil be done in 12 hours.

I hope I'll get a regular folder, however inside there will be band files, so my plan is to convert back this new folder to a regular timemachine .sparsebundle file

So the question is how do I convert that folder to timemachine .sparsebundle file

Thanks

Comment: *"can't be mounted"* what's the error? .sparesebundles should just open on double-click, same as any disk image. BTW, if you use anything other than Finder to copy a Time Machine drive, expect it to not be able to follow the hard-links etc properly & you'll end up with huge multiples of files in every backup's folder, which will be then impossible to squish back down to another drive, nor will it ever behave like a backup again, it will just be copies of your latest state.

Comment: hdiutil: attach failed - unrecognized image